How to Unhide rows greyed out below a table
All rows below a table are not shown (grey background only), and the row numbers are not shown.
The sheet is not protected.  Any ideas how to unhide?
I can change the hidden status of those rows using
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(lastTableRow+1).Hidden=false 

with no error message;
debug.print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(lastTableRow+1).Hidden 

continues to return true and the row remains hidden.
Hiding and unhiding works as expected for rows in the table.  The rows clearly exist as values can be added and retrieved.

try running the macro on a new spreadsheet

Maybe you somehow set all those rows to zero height?

Try ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False: ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15.

ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15 cured it - I guess all the rows were zero height.  Thanks everyone for your help.

p.s. ...Rows.Hidden returns true when RowHeight is 0, and changes to false when it's above about 0.4.  Although that reflects the visible result, I'm not sure it's completely logical.
